# grpc server port sharing

Tags: c#, wcf, grpc

I'm digging out to grpc as a replacement for WCF. I'm using .Net 5 and looking for a stand-alone
server solution (No ASP involved --> Concole application). That already limits the available hints and tutorials a lot :-(

Using packages grpc.Core (2.34.0), grpc.Tools (2.34.0), grpc.Net.Common (2.34.0) and Google.Protobuf (3.14.0) it is quite easy to spawn a basic server (GreeterImpl comes from some tutorial):

```
Server server = new Server();
server.Services.Add(Greeter.BindService(new GreeterImpl()));
server.Ports.Add(new ServerPort("localhost", 5001, ServerCredentials.Insecure));

server.Start();

Console.ReadKey();
```

This works fine. Server listens on port 5001.

In WCF self-hosted (based uppon http.sys) it was quite easy to host multiple WCF servers just
by specifying a different directory (minified code):

1st assembly

```
List<Uri> baseAddresses = new List<Uri>();

baseAddresses.Add(new Uri("http://localhost:5001/Service1.svc"));
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(GenericService), baseAddresses.ToArray());
host.Open();
```

2nd assembly

```
List<Uri> baseAddresses = new List<Uri>();

baseAddresses.Add(new Uri("http://localhost:5001/Service2.svc"));
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(GenericService), baseAddresses.ToArray());
host.Open();
```

It even worked with a present IIS serving other stuff on port 5001

How do I start a second server (different assembly) using the same port but different directory?
I could not find any suggestion on how to achieve that.

Comment: As a side note: if you're migrating from WCF, protobuf-net.Grpc may be a useful tool for you; see: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/tree/main/examples/wcf-port ; protobuf-net.Grpc works with both the Google (Grpc.Core) and Microsoft transports, at both client and server

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks will have a deeper look in it

Comment: There is a port sharing function in WCF. I checked the introduction of gRPC in the Microsoft documentation, and it seems that there is no such function in gRPC.

Answer (score 1):

To be running on the same port, it needs to be part of the same `Server` instance; this effectively means multiple calls to `server.Services.Add(...)` (on the same `server` instance) before calling `.Start()`, with different service instances. To do this, you might need to orchestrate your code such that you can identify all the services *before* trying to create the server. Partly, this difference is because Grpc.Core does not use Http.Sys - it is a wrapper around chttp2, which does not provide active port sharing. But in reality: this is a very common limitation *even in* systems that might use OS assistance.

Comment: On our hosted environment I'm limited to use port 443 for inbound traffic. There still need to be several completly independent grpc server instances.

Comment: @TomB you can happily have several independent grpc **services**, all running in the same server instance; you can't have multiple independent grpc **servers** (with one service each) on the same port. That's just how it works; what you're asking for isn't a thing that the API provides. Can I ask: what is the specific reason why multiple *servers* is important to you here? In what way would it be distinguishable from a single server hosting *multiple services*?

Comment: Reason is quite simple. Multiple completly independent instances of my program run simultanious on the same machine using the same port (see above comment). There is no grpc master server which then routes the data. Just a 1:1 connection using the same port but should use different directory as possible in WCF

Comment: @TomB oh, by "directory" you mean on the file system, with multiple separate processes? I assumed you meant simply routing, i.e. an http2 endpoint at "/foo/whatever" vs "/bar/something" (which *is* fine); if they're separate processes: that isn't going to work, AFAIK - *however*, it is possible that there's some super-secret voodoo that enables this that I've never heard of; I'm not holding my breath, though